# vim: delete all blank space until next non-blank character

Tags: vim, vi

Say I have the following code:

```
<p>
    Hello
</p>
```

And I want to make it

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

I would like to put the cursor in normal mode at the end of line 1, so on the ' > ' and have a command to delete all spaces until the next character. The closest I can think of is the motion

```
d/Hello
```

which deletes everything until Hello but the issue is that it deletes also the character under the cursor (the ' > ') so I end up with

```
<pHello
</p>
```

How would you do that?

Comment: Before voting to close, please read this: [Vim Questions: SO or SU](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way when you won't need to repeat this action many times.

```
JxJx
```

Explanation:

```
J           # Join current line with next one but substitute end of line with a space.
x           # Remove the space.
Jx          # Repeat same process for last line.
```

Comment: I need to do it many times and try to repeat the action via `.`, yet that only repeats the `x` not the `J`. Can you please add an example if one needs to repeat this multiple times?

Answer (score 6):

There's a `tag` text-object in vim:

- put cursor within tag, press <kbd>vat</kbd> to select entire tag
- press <kbd>:</kbd>, it becomes `:'<,'>`
- type <kbd>j</kbd>, it becomes `:'<,'>j`
- press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to join lines

---

```
:help v_at

at          "a tag block", select [count] tag blocks, from the
            [count]'th unmatched "<aaa>" backwards to the matching
            "</aaa>", including the "<aaa>" and "</aaa>".
            See |tag-blocks| about the details.
            When used in Visual mode it is made characterwise.
```

Comment: `vatJ` would get you the same results.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question because of the spaces added by `:join`.

Answer (score 2):

When standing anywhere in the second line (the one that says `Hello`), press the following keys: `^d0vatgJ`. Simply explained:

1. <kbd>^</kbd> will go to the first non-whitespace character, `H`
2. <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> will delete to the beginning of the line
3. <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> will select the entire tag
4. <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> will join all the lines without inserting spaces

If you start on the `H`, you can skip the <kbd>^</kbd> part.