# Intellij: delete all blank space until next non-blank character

Tags: intellij-idea

There is no easier way to explain what I want to do than a picture:
[image]

I would like to reduce the time it takes me to refactor HTML code by deleting all the white space behind (or before, doesn't matter that much) my caret until the next non-blank character, emphasized by the highlighted blue whitespace I would like to delete. [I found a way to do this on vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850512/vim-delete-all-blank-space-until-next-non-blank-character), but I want to do this on Intellij.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Ctrl+Alt+J` (`⌃⇧J` on Mac) on the `<a>...` line to perform the 'Join Lines' action.

More information on the feature can be found [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2007/03/using-smart-line-joins/) and [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html#editor_lines_code_blocks).

Comment: Brilliant! Though 40% of the time it's hard to nail down all the keystrokes at once (just like ctrl+k+s on VScode for all save).

Comment: @BarAkiva If a shortcut to a certain action that you use quite a lot is multi-keystroke by default, you can remap it in the **File | Settings | Keymap** dialog to something shorter like `Ctrl+Num5` or even a single-stroke `F10`. Just make sure that the bindings do not clash.

Comment: On Windows is `Ctrl+Shift+J `

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/join-lines/